# How to eval value inside a function on onClientClick event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to eval a parameter inside a function in an onclientclick event in asp.net aspx and also add return false to the onclientclick event so that the page does not refresh

The onclientclick event is an linkbutton

I want to display a modal when clicked

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkFile" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Path", "ShowModal({0}); return false;") %>' CssClass="card-body" >
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then come back and edit your question appropriately. It is not solvable in its current form.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you really should post some sample code.

Keep in mind that you can ONLY use confirm (js) for this.

you can NOT use say a jQuery.UI dialog or some such (because they don't halt code).

So, if you drop in a simple button like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="118px"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('delete this');"/>
```

So above will pop a confirm dialog like this:

[image]

If the user hits ok, then your server side client code will run. If user hits cancel, then the button does not run. So this works great for a confirm dialog - say for some delete button or some such.

However, you can NOT do the above say with a jQuery.UI or some wiget dialog add-in, since those dialogs do NOT halt code. You can however still use say some JavaScript dialog add in or prompt, but you have to modify somewhat how this works.

But, confirm('some message') for a confirmation prompt will work, and as noted, if user hits cancel, then the server side button event code will not trigger or run.

You of course can also pass a value/parameter in that client side oncclient  event, but it depends where and when (is this a data bound control?). So the where and when to add on to the above needs some context.

Say this might be a gridview or some such?

Now, as noted you can really only use confirm() this way. if we are using say some dialog system, a different approach is required.

I do suggest that you pick one, learn it, and stick with it.

I suggest to use jQuery.UI. There is  a HUGE chance that your site by default has jQuery, so adding in jQuery.UI for nice looking dialogs is thus not all that much extra work.

So, now, lets do this with a jQuery.UI modal dialog.

We will have this markup:

```
           <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete record" Width="118px"
            OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this)"/>
        <br />

           <div id="mydeletediv" style="display:none">
               <h2>Do you really want to delete this</h2>
           </div>

        <script>
            mydelpromptok = false
            function mydelprompt(btn) {

                if (mydelpromptok) {
                    mydelprompt = false
                    return true
                }

                myDialog = $("#mydeletediv")
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: 'Confirm delete',
                    modal: true,
                    width: '400px',
                    appendTo: "form",
                    position: { my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: btn },
                    buttons: {
                        Delete : function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                            mydelprompt = true
                            btn.click()
                        },
                        cancel: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                })
                return false
            }
   </script>
```

And we thus get this now:

[image]

Now, you are quite much free to put anything you want in that prompt div - even pictures - and even text boxes, check boxes etc. So, whatever you put in that div will display in the dialog.

If user hits delete, then the server side button click will fire. If they hit cancel, then the button click code for code behind will not run.

Comment: I want when the button clicked a modal is shown

Comment: right, but what kind of modal popup do you want to use? There are 100's of different kinds you can choose from. But I do suggest jQuery.UI dialogs - they work rather well.

Comment: See my code above its the bootstrap modal

Comment: The bootstrap modals suck, because you have a VERY difficult time controlling the button click. I posted a jQuery.UI example. I find the bootstrap modal dialogs too hard to control the button click. They are nice to pop a dialog, but getting them to work with the button click for the option(s) click sucks big time, so I still recommend jQuery.UI, and I never did get bootstrap modal dialogs to work with much success to control click of a simple button like I did above. your look + feel of whatever you put in that div can be bootstrap themed, but if you want to use bootstrap dialogs? good luck!

Comment: Just looking at your question, maybe you NEVER want a true value to be returned? That being the case, then drop in a HTML button, and not a asp.net one. However, if you do need a prompt of some sort, and to conditional run the server side button code, then what I posted is the way to go. However, if never true is to be returned, then what you have looks ok.

Comment: I ask the above, since if you always want to return false, then what you have can work. However, the button cannot use a server side expression, unless this is a databind event inside of a grid, or you execute a page.DataBind(). However, since that is a server side expression, then you can (have to) set the on-client click in the page load event. However, if the goal is true/false with some kind of dialog, then you have to use what I outlined above. But, move that server side expression to code behind. (unless this is a grid view of some type).

Comment: the link button is inside a listview, so i can use Eval but i want to eval a parameter in the function and at the same time make it to return false so that the page does not refresh. the value is from the database thats y i need to use the Eval

Comment: ok, then you should be able to do this. I had assumed the click event was to return true or false based on a dialog (maybe cofirm to delete a row). Since you don't want (or care) and don't need a true/false to control button click post-back? Just drop in a HTML input button - it will not post back. So dump the link button. You can drop in   HTML button - without "runat=server", then it will not post back. Just use the onclick event which is now a client side click with your current js expression.  So you don't need (or care about my post above - it don't apply). use a input html button.

Comment: Thanks it works when i tried with <button class="col-12 btn btn-outline-info card-body"  type="button"  onclick='ShowModal("  <%# Eval("Path") %> ");' > </button>

Answer (score 0):

It works with the code below:

```
 <button class="col-12 btn btn-outline-info card-body" type="button" onclick='ShowModal(" <%# Eval("Path") %> ");' > </button>
```

No need to use the linkbutton and runat="server"